# Tune for Aishes Chayil

Tags: music, provenance, aishes-chayil

In all of my experience at Friday night meals, *Aishes Chayil* is always sung to the same tune. In the US and Israel, in Yeshivos and hotels, I've only heard one tune used.

What's the origin of this tune? Any information about it would be helpful.

Comment: I've heard different tunes

Comment: Shlomo Carlebach also had a tune as well a popular one by Shalsheles

Comment: @Jewels Shalsheles's song (from Connections) was released last Chanukah time. How can it compete?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This tune was composed by [Ben Zion Shenker](http://www.milkenarchive.org/people/view/all/561/Shenker,+Ben+Zion) of the Modzitzer chassidim. I can't really do justice to his legacy in words here, but see the bio I've linked. His place at almost every shabbos table in the world is well deserved.

And a link to a recording of Ben Zion Shenker himself singing this: http://www.piyut.org.il/tradition/841.html?currPerformance=1093

Comment: For all who are concerned: there's a cappella / sefirah-safe recording of Shenker's recording here: http://www.milkenarchive.org/people/view/all/561/Shenker,+Ben+Zion#/works/view/345